# Definition of inner automorphism on operator algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In groups and rings, we usually define inner automorphisms to be those of the form $\phi(x) = axa^{-1}$ for some invertible element $a$.

But in operator algebras, an inner automorphism is almost always defined as something of the form $\phi(x) = uxu^* = uxu^{-1}$ for some **unitary** element $u$.

Is there a good reason why the definition in an operator algebra setting is different/unexpected? What do we call an automorphism in a $C^*$-algebra when it is a conjugation by some non-unitary invertible element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a $*$-algebra, then by definition an automorphism $\phi: A \rightarrow A$ commutes with the $*$, that is, $\phi(x)^{*} = \phi(x^{*})$.

If we define $\phi$ to be conjugation by some unitary element of $A$, then this property holds automatically.

If we conjugate by a non-unitary element then this property need not hold.

I am guessing that an inner automorphism commutes with the $*$-operation if and only if it is given by conjugation with a unitary element, but I don't see how to prove this right now.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good way of putting it. I'm able to prove your last statement partially. Let $in(a) \in Aut(A)$ be conjugation by $a \in A$. If $in(a)$ happens to be a $*$-automorphism, then $in(a) = in((a^*)^{-1})$. Since the kernel of $in: A^{-1} \to Aut(A)$ is just $Z(A)\cap A^{-1}$ then this shows that $a$ and $(a^*)^{-1}$ are in the same coset of the centre of $A$. If the centre is trivial, then $a$ is unitary.

Comment: You cannot really get better than that. If $a\in Z(A)$ is invertible, then $axa^{-1}=x$ is a $*$-homomorphism.